# How to diagnose "setting a property that has only a getter" problem in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

When loading one of our webpages firebug shows the absolutely dumb error message "setting a property that has only a getter" without telling anything about what property, what object or (God beware!) what line in which script. 8-{}

The "break on errors" feature does not work, nor does the "show stack on errors" do anything. Unfortunately the initialization code of the page is very complex, so it is quite impossible to find the problem by code inspection. Any ideas on how to find a problem like this?

I am using Firefox 3.6.13 and have Firebug 1.6.0 and Javascript Debugger 0.9.88.1 installed, in case that matters.

Answer (score 1):

You could start [reducing the web page to a testcase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Reducing_testcases). While time-consuming, this will get you to the answer.

Alternatively, if you build Firefox from source, you could est a break point on the lines that mention your message (refer to http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/search?string=JSMSG_GETTER_ONLY) and then use [DumpJSStack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Debugging_Mozilla_on_Windows_FAQ#Debugging_JavaScript) from the debugger and/or get some help on irc.mozilla.org with debugging.

If you do make a minimized testcase, please [report the issue to Firebug developers](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/list).

Answer (score 0):

This might(or might not) give you an idea where to look: http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum91/4278.htm